# why when i want to override the method onCreateDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

hi every body please i would like to show a dialog Personalized but i want to 
override the method

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
// Get the layout inflater
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

// Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
// Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
// Add action buttons
       .setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // sign in the user ...
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
           }
       });
return builder.create();
```

}

this code is from the android documentation but i want to override it in my activitymain but in the suggestions doesnt appear that method i would like to know why?   the method appears with the same name but with  diferent parameters

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onCreateDialog of the Activity class is deprecated. Use [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog(int,%20android.os.Bundle)) instead.